# RestKit freezable operations similar to MKNetworkKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

In the past I have used MKNetworkKit to implement freezable operations where a network request is automatically queued if the network status is offline and automatically sent when the network comes back up. This is done using the MKNetworkKit concept of "freezable" operations.

I'm switching to RestKit for my new projects because I greatly prefer the RestKit Object Mapping for Core Data, but I'm not finding anything analogous to the freezable operations of MKNetworkKit.

Do I have to manage this myself with the built in RestKit reachability code and my own operation queues or am I missing something RestKit has that would provide similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing RestKit does not have this feature. It should be relatively easy to add using, as you say, the reachability support offered by AFNetworking. You could add this functionality into a subclass of `RKObjectManager`, or you could add it directly to `RKObjectManager` and raise a pull request.

It's probably worth discussion on the [RestKit google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/restkit) if you are interested in raising a pull request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll explore adding it to the core functionality via a pull request once I make the changes. I'll post to the group first as you recommended.